# PHP Netbeans getter and setter for static variables

Tags: php, netbeans, static, setter, getter

It is possible to generate getter and setter methods for **static** member variables of a PHP class in Netbeans? It seems that this is not possible. Is there any rational reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

This is a missing feature. Open a feature request at the netbeans PHP bugtracker.